# Select row from DataGridView and place it in a textbox

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows form application which has a datagridview to display a menu full of meals.

[image]

I want to be able to allow the user to choose a seat number and then select a row and once the row is selected all the information in that row to be put in the available textbox below which will then be submitted in a new xml file titled `order.xml`.

So far I have the the saving to the xml part sorted, but I can't seem to get the datagridview task done.

Code to save the data in the order.xml file.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("order.xml");
        XElement root = new XElement("MenuInfo");
        root.Add(new XElement("Data1", dataGridView.DataSource));
        root.Add(new XElement("Data2", _seat));
        root.Add(new XElement("Data3", buttonTable1.Text));
        root.Add(new XElement("Data4", lbPrice.Text));
        doc.Element("Menu").Add(root);
        doc.Save("order.xml");

        MessageBox.Show("The order has been placed.");
```

Comment: `root.Add(new XElement("Data1", dataGridView.DataSource));` what do you get (expect to get) from this line??? - You should probably write a function that pulls a List<string> or/and string[] from a DGV or DataTable row. Try it and come back with any problems you encounter

Comment: @TaW From that code I only get this inserted

<MenuInfo>
    <Data1>Meal</Data1>
    <Data2>seat1</Data2>
    <Data3>Table 1</Data3>
    <Data4>Price</Data4>
  </MenuInfo>

It does not output the full Meal name, I'm not sure what you mean by the function part.

Comment: what is the datagridview task? what are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: @FadiBanna The DataGridView is displaying an xml file titled menu.xml. I am trying to allow the user to select a row and soon as it is selected it should display in the bottom textbox with all the information on that row. Does that make sense?

Comment: well I think you should consider editing your post so this point is clear,  you posted a code that is irrelevant to the problem you are having , you should post the code you tried to get selected row into the textbox , your question does not have anything to do with XML , please edit the post so we can help you.

Comment: `List<string> getDvgRowData(DataGridView  dgv, int row)
        {
            List<string> data = new List<string>();
            DataGridViewRow dgvr = dgv.Rows[row];
            foreach (DataGridViewCell dgvc in dgvr.Cells) data.Add(dgvc.ToString());
            return data;
        }` and `textBox1.Text = String.Join(" ", getDvgRowData(dataGridView1, 1));`

Comment: @TaW If it is not too much trouble, can you please explain to me what that code does as I am completely new to C#.

Comment: It collects the values from all the cells in one row of a datagridview. Don't ake it as it is! It just shows the basics. You probably should take the fields one by one, each with its own formatting string, not all in a loop!! - but that depends on whether you the data to b saved to xml or to be displayed in the textbox.. You also may want to replce the " " by a "\t" to allow better splitting when retirving the xml data...

Answer (score 0):

You can react on the RowEnter-Event, which fires if the user enter a row. Do following then:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowEnter(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            var yourGrid = sender as DataGridView;

            if (yourGrid != null)
            {
                var row = yourGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;

                if (row != null)
                {
                    //Here you have access to the actual row.
                    //So simply get the string foreach column you need
                    string myStringForTextEdit = Convert.ToString(row["MealID"]) + Convert.ToString(row["Food"]) +
                                                 Convert.ToString(row["Price"]) + Convert.ToString(row["Time"]) +
                                                 Convert.ToString(row["Quantity"]);

                    myTextEdit.Text = myStringForTextEdit;
                }
            }
        }
```

This simple example use the RowEnter-Event gets the current row and build a string based on all row Values.

I hope this helps.